# Flutter First Http Request Not Firing

Tags: http, flutter, dart

I'm developing a Flutter application, now working on authentication. When a user enters their credentials, I send a post request to my server (.NET Core). The problem is the first request (login in this case) doesn't fire and doesn't timeout, basically it stays in an infinite loop. If I change something in the app that triggers a hot reload, then the request fires and the next ones work just fine. Seems like a odd behaviour.

I've tried to await for the response and also tried using .then() clause, both have the same behaviour:

```
Future<Response> post(String path, String body) async {
    final response = await http.post(url + path, headers: {
      HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json'
    }, body: body);

    // .then((res) => print(res));

    ...
  }
```

Been stuck on this for 2 days and can't find a logical explanation for this behaviour. Anyone has/had the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this should help you

```
post(String path, String body) async {
 final response = 
       await http.post(url + path,
                 headers: { HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json' },
                 body: body); 
  print (response.body()); 
}
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I had.. Don't know what the problem was, but it is working now.

Comment: The problem was you were trying 
 // .then((res) => print(res));

intead of 
print (response.body()); 

Anyways it's great that it's working now.

Comment: No, that part was commented because as told, I also tried without async/await, therefore the .then() clause. Thanks anyway!